# How to solve @apollo modules causes problems In react project?

Tags: reactjs, apollo

Ex - I installed `@apollo/react-components` to use `ApolloProvider` in a react project and it causes the following error:

> ./node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.esm.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'apollo-client'

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @U4EA unfortunately no. As far as I can remember I moved on with totally new approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because withApollo is now part of @apollo/client. Changing the import to this should resolve the error.

```
import { withApollo } from '@apollo/client/react/hoc'
```